# How can i shade my density plot in r using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

```
library(dslabs)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

murders %>%
  filter(region == c("Northeast","South")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(total, y = ..count.. , col = region  )) +
  geom_density()
```

This does produce the plot but i want it to be shaded below the line...is there any function with the help of which i can do that?

Comment: Use `fill=...` in aes clause?

Comment: yes....it's working but they are overlapping is there any way to shade them without overlapping. I mean, to overlap in such a way that we could see both the colors below the respective line.

Comment: Try `alpha = 0.5`.

Comment: Perfect! Now, Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Add the fill and alpha aesthetics to show both, despite the overlap.  Play with the levels of alpha to adjust how much bleed.  Use the `guides()` to remove the legend.

```
murders %>% filter(region == c("Northeast","South")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(total, y = ..count.. , col = region, fill = region, alpha = 0.5)) +
  geom_density() +
  guides(alpha = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!, this guides() function will really come in handy..